# C++ Pointer Dereference Multiplication

Tags: c++, arduino

I am currently programming an arduino and am using C++ objects to do so. I've run into a weird issue when I try to multiply the values that are being pointed at. Referring to the code below, when I run the program, var3 and var4 end up having two different values. Why is this? They are essentially multiplying the same values (or so I believe). Any help?

```
 long var1 = info->accelXYZ[0];
 long var2 = info->taughtAccelXYZ[0];
 long var3 = var1*var2;

 long var4 = info->accelXYZ[0]*info->taughtAccelXYZ[0];
```

Comment: Have you properly initialized `info`'s members?  If that hasn't been done, then the multiplication behavior is undefined.

Comment: What type are the `accelXYZ` and `taughtAccelXYZ` members?

Comment: Hi, they are integers. These are being initialized too.

Comment: @Teague There are several different types of integers.  `int`, `long`, `short`, etc.  Which one?

Comment: Hi Paul, they are of type 'int'

Comment: @Teague Have you considered that overflow may have occurred?  An `int * int` gives you an `int`, not a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're overflowing in one of the situations.

The multiplication of `var1` and `var2` (both `long`) gives a `long` which is then loaded into `var3`.

If both `info->accelXYZ[0]` and `info->taughtAccelXYZ[0]` are `int` (for example), the result of the multiplication will be `int` which is then loaded into a `long`.

The intermediate `int` form may be overflowing, something you can see in the following snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("int has %d bytes\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("long has %d bytes\n",sizeof(long));

    int a = INT_MAX;
    int b = 2;

    long var1 = a;
    long var2 = b;

    long var3 = a * b;
    long var4 = var1 * var2;

    printf ("var3=%ld\n", var3);
    printf ("var4=%ld\n", var4);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
int has 4 bytes
long has 8 bytes
var3=-2
var4=4294967294
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason why `var3` may end up with a different value than `var4` is *integer overflow*. This happens when both multiplicands fit in an `int`, but the product doesn't.

Since `int`s and `long`s have different sizes on Arduino Uno<sup>*</sup>, the computation of `var3` is different from computation of `var4`.

When you compute `var3`, the multiplication is done in `long`s on the initial values that fit in an `int`, so the result of multiplication is not translated. When you compute `var4`, the computation is done in `int`s, and then promoted to `long`. However, by then the result is already truncated, which results in the discrepancy that you are observing.

To make `var4` the same correct value as `var3`, add a cast to `long` to one of the multiplicands, like this:

```
long var4 = (info->accelXYZ[0])*((long)info->taughtAccelXYZ[0]);
```

<sup>*</sup> `int` has 16 bits, while `long` has 32 bits.